# IBM X3850 M2 (7233) server hard drives - Novice help needed

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ibm-xseries

We have just bought a used IBM X3850 M2 (7233) server. The plan being to use it for CFD analysis calculations, taking the workload off our workstations.

Not being an expert on these matters... Can I just install any single 2.5" SAS hard drive into one of the front drive bays, install an OS and then be good to go? Or do we have to use some sort of RAID set up and specific drives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty much install any 2.5" SAS or even SATA drives in the front drive bays and install an OS. I have the same machine and have used ibm server grade SAS 2.5" drives, as well as cheap 2.5" 250gb Seagate laptop SATA drives and installed OS and booted from them without difficulty. Only issue is controller won't see > 2TB (though the disk will still usually be usable, you just won't be able to access any more than the first 2TB).